# r: normalmixEM not consistent?

Tags: r, expectation-maximization

I have the following data: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00083355432555420222

I want to fit a mixture density of two normal distributions.

I have the formula:
\begin{align}
f(l)=\pi \phi(l;\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)+(1-\pi)\phi(l;\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)
\end{align}

my R code is:

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,k=2,fast=TRUE)

pi<-normalmix$lambda[1]
    mu1<-normalmix$mu[1]
mu2<-normalmix$mu[2]
    sigma1<-normalmix$sigma[1]
sigma2<-normalmix$sigma[2]
```

Now I have the problem, that the output is not consistent, i.e. every time I run the code, I get different outputs! And they are very different, no small differences, which could be due to the precision of the numerical procedures.

E.g.
sometimes for pi I get

```
[1] 0.2653939
```

or

```
[1] 0.3318069
```

I already recognized, that sometimes the numbering is changed, so the pi of 0.7 would be equal to a pi of 0.3. Okay, I got this, I don't know why the R procedures does this, but this would not be a problem. But the problem is, that the outputs are way to different, sometimes I even get an error message (german):
Fehler in while (dl > eps && iter < maxit) { : 
  Fehlender Wert, wo TRUE/FALSE nötig ist

Also, the number of iterations is very different, from 29 up to 1000 ......

edit: I now tried to set the initial values manually....
In the Rmanual it says:

> Lambda: "Initial value of mixing proportions. Automatically repeated
>   as necessary to pro- duce a vector of length k , then normalized to
>   sum to 1"

I started to try it with giving different values of lambda:

1.

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,lambda=c(0.5,0.5),k=2,fast=TRUE)
normalmix$loglik
    normalmix$mu
normalmix$sigma
```

which gives a loglik of `617.2996` and the parameters:

```
> normalmix$mu
    [1]  0.0003769442 -0.0008892282
    > normalmix$sigma
[1] 0.02814997 0.01232638
```

2.

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,lambda=c(0.8,0.2),k=2,fast=TRUE)
normalmix$loglik
    normalmix$mu
normalmix$sigma
```

which also gives a loglik of `617.2996` ? and the parameters

```
> normalmix$mu
    [1]  0.0003767148 -0.0008892515
    > normalmix$sigma
[1] 0.02814819 0.01232488
```

mh, I don' know....

then, I tried it with different values of $\mu$:

1.

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,mu=c(-0.001,0.002),k=2,fast=TRUE)
normalmix$loglik
    normalmix$mu
normalmix$sigma
```

which also leads to a loglik of `617.2996` and the parameter output:

```
> normalmix$mu
    [1]  0.0003767138 -0.0008892516
    > normalmix$sigma
[1] 0.02814818 0.01232487
```

2.

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,mu=c(0.02,0.01),k=2,fast=TRUE)
normalmix$loglik
    normalmix$mu
normalmix$sigma
```

which again! leads to a loglik of `617.2996` and the parameter output:

```
> normalmix$mu
    [1]  0.0003769462 -0.0008892280
    > normalmix$sigma
[1] 0.02814999 0.01232639
>
```

what should I do now?

Comment: This could habe to do with local minima for the mixture likelihood. Have you tried running the code with the same starting values every time? Does the behaviour still occur then? Imo error message is too unspecific to to be diagnosed from here. You can use traceback() to see where the error occurred. Also, possible bugs might better be reported to the package authors.

Comment: yes, I just compiled/run the SAME code several times, this gives different outputs! So I did NOT change any values @Momo !

Comment: If you have not passed ANY values as starting values, the values will be RANDOMly generated. From the docs: "If NULL, then the initial value is randomly generated from a normal distribution determined by binning the data." So try passing the SAME starting values for mu and sigma a couple of times and see if it is still "inconsistent". If not, the starting values are probably the reason and the algorithm is stuck in local maxima. If so, run the algorithm with different starting values and take the solution that had the highest likelihood over all runs.

Comment: @Momo I did what you said and what should I do now?

Comment: Well, you now showed that the results are not inconsistent... So its just that the algorithm did not numerically find the optimum before termination or local maxima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the default number of iterations (`maxit=1000`) is not enough to guarantee the convergence of the EM algorithm in general and you have to fiddle a bit with this (and sometimes other) feature.  It seems like `maixt=10000` produces stable results. See the following code (run it several times to convince yourself).

```
normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,k=2,fast=TRUE,maxit=10000)

pi<-normalmix$lambda[1]
    mu1<-normalmix$mu[1]
mu2<-normalmix$mu[2]
    sigma1<-normalmix$sigma[1]
sigma2<-normalmix$sigma[2]

c(pi,mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2)
```

Now, check the fit of the estimated mixture.

```
mix2 <- function(x) return( pi*dnorm(x,mu1,sigma1)+(1-pi)*dnorm(x,mu2,sigma2))

vec <- seq(-0.05,0.05,0.0001)

plot(vec,mix2(vec),type="l",col="red")
hist(dat,probability=T,add=T)
```

Comment: this is a real improvement and I will accept your answer, but one last thing:

Sometimes I still get values for pi like [1] 0.9818572 so it is not really perfect, should I care about this or ignore this?

Comment: Are these results obtained with `maixt=10000`? I get always the same result if I specify this number of iterations.

Comment: I think I see your point now. Let me check ...

Comment: it seems, that there are two pairs of possible solutions, the first pair is 0.6172075 and 0.3827929. This is the same solution I think, since the ordering is just changed, so the mu1 is now the mu2. Ok, but the second pair is (this occurs more seldom):
0.01814275 and 0.981857

Comment: I think you have to increase the precision, the number of initial points and the number of iterations. The rest is just related to the non-uniqueness of the estimation of MLE in a Gaussian mixture (as you mention). Check `normalmix<-normalmixEM(dat,k=2,fast=FALSE,maxit=10000,epsilon = 1e-16,maxrestarts=1000)`. I would rather model these data using a skew-t in order to avoid local maxima.

Comment: the first pair, the 0.617 and 0.383 have a loglik of 617.2996 and the second pair, the 0.018 and 0.982 have a loglik of 613.9351 the second pair is quite seldom, you have to rerun the code for like 10 times

Comment: I modelled a (non skewed) t distribution in the section of my thesis before, after the mixing distribution I will fit a generalized hyperbolid distribution. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Good. The only issue with the generalized hyperbolic distribution is that it has different tail behaviour in each direction while other skew-t distributions have the same tail behaviour.

Comment: even with your improved solution, so with maxit epsilon and maxrestarts I still get the second pair as a solution sometimes!

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem with Guassian mixtures. The only way to recognise the best choice is by conducting a model comparison via some technique. Numerical methods are likely to get stuck in local maxima. Mixtures of distributions, although flexible, are more appropriate when the features of the data come from a mixing of several populations in the same data set.